# Does eating food cooked with a microwave reduce the haemoglobin count of the blood?

Tags: nutrition, microwaves

HealthyHolisticLiving writes in [Facts About Microwave Ovens That Will Make You Never Want To Use One Again](http://www.healthy-holistic-living.com/facts-about-microwave-ovens-that-will-make-you-never-want-to-use-one-again.html?t=snjv)

> The blood samples from test subjects who had consumed microwaved foods demonstrated decreased lymphocytes (white blood cells) and decreased haemoglobin and cholesterol values, combined with increased luminescence or energy of luminescent bacteria, explained here.

Did the described research really happen and if so has it been successfully replicated?

Comment: The study in question was supposedly conducted by Swiss researchers Hertel and Blanc.  https://www.metabunk.org/debunked-the-dangers-of-microwave-ovens.t1288/ says that their work was never published.

Comment: I was going to call this nonsense, then I got to the point where they claimed luminescent bacteria found in blood. Blood does not shine in the dark!

Comment: @JanDvorak : The claim sounds like a lay persons reading of "in a study they put luminescent bacteria into the blood and the luminenscence was increased in cases of microwaved food".

Comment: @NateEldredge: Is that an answer?

Comment: @Oddthinking: No, it doesn't address whether the research happened nor whether it has been replicated.  But I thought it might be a helpful start for someone else to investigate.

Comment: I would point out just from your description that it's not necessarily the microwave that causes the problems, even if it was a good study. Maybe people who eat a lot of convenient microwave food tend to be the people who don't eat the healthier home-made meals or something along those lines. To demonstrate the problem was the microwave, the different groups would need to eat the same exact food prepared both ways.

Comment: The "study" by Blanc & Hertel was published in the [Journal Franz Weber](http://www.ffw.ch/en/journal) (definitely not peer reviewed) in 1992. Link to a pdf of that 1992 journal: http://www.ffw.ch/uploads/journal/archivos/JFW_1992_19_DE.pdf . The article in question starts near the bottom of page 5.